# C[a,b] with Sup-Norm is complete

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I came across many pages claiming to prove that $C[a,b]$ with the Supremum norm:
$||f(t)|| = sup_{t\in[a,b]}|f(t)|$ is complete, i.e. that every Cauchy-sequence with elements in $C[a,b]$ converges to a point in $C[a,b]$.
Few examples:

- [Is the space $C[0,1]$ complete?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97356/is-the-space-c0-1-complete)
- https://mast.queensu.ca/~speicher/Section3.pdf
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5UjOR1w5NE

All of the examples mentioned above start with showing point-wise convergence to a sequence $(f_n)$ However, none of these examples (as far as I can tell) properly address the issue of uniform convergence of the Cauchy sequence $(f_n)$.

Since $(f_n)$ is Cauchy, $\forall\epsilon>0$ $\;\exists N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $||f_n(t)-f_m(t)||<{\frac\epsilon2}$  $\;\forall n,m>N_1$ $\;\forall t\in[a,b]$

$\Rightarrow sup_{t\in[a,b]}|f_n(t)-f_m(t)|<{\frac\epsilon2}$ $\Rightarrow|f_n(t)-f_m(t)|<{\frac\epsilon2}$  $\;\forall t\in[a,b]$.

In particular for each fixed $t_0\in[a,b]$ $|f_n(t_0)-f_m(t_0)|<\epsilon$ $\;\forall n,m>N_1$ Thus, the sequence $(f_n(t_0))$, which is a sequence of real numbers (or complex numbers, that does not matter for the sake of this proof), is also Cauchy.

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, the sequence $(f_n(t_0))$ converges to a point $f(t_0)$, i.e. $\forall\epsilon>0$ $\;\exists N_{t_0}$ s.t. $\forall n>N_{t_0}$ $|f_n(t_0)-f(t_0)|<\epsilon$.

We can construct $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to obtain **point-wise convergence**. However, for every $x\in[a,b]$ there is a unique $N_x$, which is a function of $x$, to obtain convergence of the sequence $(f_n(x))$ to $f(x)$.

In order to obtain uniform convergence, one must show that $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists M\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|f_n(t)-f(t)|<\epsilon$ $\forall n>M$ $\forall t\in[a,b]$. Using the triangle inequality:

$|f_n(t)-f(t)|\le |f_n(t)-f_m(t)|+|f_m(t)-f(t)|$

We need to find an $M$ such that the first expression above is less than $\epsilon$ for all $t\in[a,b]$. Choosing $M>N_1$ is obvious, therefore:

$|f_n(t)-f(t)|\le {\frac\epsilon2}+|f_m(t)-f(t)|$

However, what is the selection of $M$ that would make the third expression ($|f_m(t)-f(t)|$) less than ${\frac\epsilon2}$?

Since we proved point-wise convergence, we can find $N_x$ locally, but there is no guarantee that there is a number $N$ such that the inequality is true for all $t\in[a,b]$. Furthermore, proving that the third expression ($|f_m(t)-f(t)|$) is less than ${\frac\epsilon2}$ is the same as proving uniform convergence.

Your help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong if you claim that uniform convergence is not addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/97377/446262). The author of that answer wrote “Next you go on to showing that $f_n$ also converges to $f$ in norm”, which, since the norm here is the $\sup$ norm, is *exactly* the same thing as asserting that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Comment: I assume I simply don't understand the explanation. Trust me, I read through all the responses, yet could not get an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to select some $M$, the number $N_1$ is completely sufficient. Then you get, with $n,m>N_1$
$$
|f_n(t)-f(t)|\le \fracϵ2+ |f_m(t)-f(t)|
$$
as you found. Now the $n$ on the left side is (almost) completely independent of the $m$ on the right side, this inequality is valid for all $m>N_1$, thus also for some $m$ where from the pointwise convergence 
$$
|f_m(t)-f(t)|<\fracϵ2.
$$
Thus the $|f_n(t)-f(t)|<ϵ$, indeed one could sharpen this to
$$
|f_n(t)-f(t)|\le \fracϵ2+ \inf_{m>N_1}|f_m(t)-f(t)|=\fracϵ2
$$
as that infimum is obviously zero.

Comment: "as you found. Now the n on the left side is (almost) completely independent of the m on the right side, this inequality is valid for all m>N1, thus also for some m where from the pointwise convergence " - I didn't quite get that part. The pointwise convergence is, as the name suggests, point-wise. You claim that you can find an m for which the inequality is less than epsilon\2 for all t? Isn't that exactly the definition of uniform convergence? I think i'm looking for a more formal approach, yet can't seem to find one - unless there is a basic misunderstanding

Comment: The $N_1$ and thus $n$ comes from the Cauchy property. With that and $m>N_1$, the Cauchy property gives the first estimate $\fracϵ2$ on the right side which eliminates the $n$ from the right side. Now for fixed $t$ and each $m>N_1$ the right side expression $\fracϵ2+ |f_m(t)-f(t)|$ is a bound for the left side. By the pointwise convergence, almost all of these bounds are smaller than $ϵ$. What this accomplishes is that the variable $m$ that could depend on $t$ for $|f_m(t)-f(t)|<\fracϵ2$ gets translated into a fixed $n$ in $|f_n(t)-f(t)|<ϵ$ that is valid for all $t$.