# Proof that pointwise convergent functions converge uniformly

Tags: functional-analysis

I am working on a proof that $C(\langle a,b \rangle)$ with sup metric is complete metric space and I am stuck at some point while proving.

Because $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, for every $x\in\langle a,b \rangle$ is a sequence $(f_n(x))$ real convergent sequence with limit denoted by $f(x)$. So we got that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f$, that means for every $x\in\langle a,b \rangle$ exists $m_{0,x}$ such that for every $m>m_{0,x}$ $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$.

To prove that $(f_n)$ converges $f$ uniformly, we use triangle inequality
$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|+|f_m(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon$.

The first expression $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|$ is by Cauchy's property really smaller than $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ but how to choose $m_0$ in a way that it doesn't depend on $x\in\langle a,b \rangle$ so $|f_m(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ would be true? $m_0$ as maximum of $m_{0,x}$ doesn't work, because it might be $\infty$. How to choose it?
Thank you

Comment: You are using too little information; pointwise convergence does not imply uniform convergence, so you need to use something more than that the original sequence converges pointwise.  Anyway, this is not research level, so will be closed.

Comment: What is $\langle a,b \rangle$ for you? Do you mean $[a,b]$?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I am used to this notation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the space $C[0,1]$ complete?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97356/is-the-space-c0-1-complete)