# Space of measurable functions not normable

Tags: measure-theory, functions, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite nonzero measure space, and let $L_0$ the set of (equivalence classes of) measurable real-valued functions on it.

This should be a classical question, but why $L_0$ cannot be normed?

Ps. Also a reference would be fine, since I imagine this is straighforward..

Edit, could we use this result (see [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA207&lpg=PA207&dq=not%20normable%20space&source=bl&ots=pasSXohZGv&sig=08ad5DhMbW2jOcwGbGxGt9NWfU0&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJiK_t6b7PAhVEtBQKHdgICxIQ6AEITjAE#v=onepage&q=not%20normable%20space&f=false)): *A locally convex Hausdorff space is normable if and only if it has a bounded neighborhood of zero.*

Comment: What do you mean by "can't be normed"?

Comment: The space of bounded, measurable functions can be equipped with the supremum norm (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127530/space-of-bounded-measurable-functions)). If the space of (possibly unbounded) measurable functions cannot be equipped with a norm, then I suspect it has something to do with measurable functions which aren't bounded

Comment: @measure_theory, indeed I asked about $L_0$, and not $L_p$ with $p \in [1,\infty]$ (your example is precisely $L_\infty$..)

Comment: @nombre That you cannot define any function $\|\cdot \|: L_0 \to \mathbf{R}$ which is also a norm (hence, with the properties of nonnegativity, omogeneity, and subadditivity)

Comment: @Nduccio: Then it can, as can any real vector space $E$, since given a basis $\beta : I \longrightarrow E$ of $E$, $\sum \limits_{i \in I} x_i.\beta_i \mapsto \sum \limits_{i \in I} |x_i|$ is a norm, and $E$ admits a basis by virtue of the incomplete basis theorem.
In the result you cite, the space already has a topology, or equivalently, you have some contraints on the resulting topology, which is different.

Comment: @nombre Maybe I am wrong, but the quoted result just says that the "non-normability" of $L_0$ would follow from the existence of a topology on $L_0$ itself making it a locally convex Hausdorff space with a bounded neighborhood of $0$..?

Comment: In this article, the space already has a topology (the product topology), and what they prove is that there can be no norm which induces the same topology. In your case, you didn't mention a topology for $L_0$ so the same can't be said.

Comment: Rephrasing nombre's concern: given a Hamel basis for your space (one exists by an argument which in general requires the axiom of choice), you can easily construct a norm for it. Thus as a *vector space* it is normable, as any real vector space is. It can only fail to be normable as a *topological vector space*, where you are already given some topology.