# Show that the metric space C[a,b] is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

Prove that the metric space $C[a,b]$ is complete.

Where $C[a,b]$ is the collection of continuous $f:[a,b] → R$ and $||f|| = sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$, such that $\rho (f,g) = ||f - g||$ is a metric on $C[a,b]$.

attempt in proof:

Recall that a metric space X is said to be complete if and only if every Cauchy sequence $x_n \in X$ converges to some point in $X$.

Let $f_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $ C[a,b]$, then $\forall \epsilon > 0,$ there is $N$ such that $||f_n - f_m|| < \epsilon$ for $n , m \geq N$ implies $||f_n - f_m || = sup |f_n - f_m | < \epsilon$.

Now for

$x \in [a,b]$, $|f_n - f_m | \leq sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \epsilon$ for $n \geq N$.

Thus $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$ .

And each $f_n$ is continous on $[a,b]$, and $f_n → f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$.

Thus, $f \in C[a,b]$. So $C[a,b]$ is complete.

Can someone please give some feedback? I don't know if I can conclude that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$. Can someone please help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You almost proved that there exists a function f to which f converges pointwise. You need to prove that f is continuous!

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97356/is-the-space-c0-1-complete, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183725/question-about-cauchy-sequence-in-ck?lq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71121/space-of-bounded-continuous-functions-is-complete?lq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718443/cauchy-sequence-of-functions-and-uniform-convergence?lq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83830/how-to-show-that-c-c0-1-is-a-banach-space, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/9321/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your argument works. There are two key ideas in this type of argument. One is to begin by *finding* the limit, and then prove it has whatever property we want. The other is the "$\varepsilon/3$" trick, which helps you relate regularity of the limit back to regularity of the members of the sequence.

In this case, the first idea goes through smoothly. You define $f$ to be the pointwise limit of the $f_n$. This exists because each sequence of numbers $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy (specifically, $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \leq \| f_n - f_m \|_\infty$), and the real numbers are complete. Now we use the second idea, by noting that for any $n$ we have

$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|+|f_n(y)-f(y)|.$$

Now how can you control these three terms?

Comment: So since $f_n$ is continuous , there is an $\delta  > 0$ such that $|x - y| < \delta $ implies $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < \epsilon /3$ . If $|x - y| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |f(x) - f_n(x) | + | f_n(x) - f_n(y)| + |f_n(y) - f(y)| < \epsilon/3 + \epsilon/3 + \epsilon/3 = \epsilon$ And so for $| x- y| < \delta$ we have $|f(x)- f(y)| < \epsilon$? Then I can conclude the proof?

Comment: @Mahidevran You have controlled the second term correctly. You need to use the convergence to control the first and third terms. Hint: you control the first and third terms in the exact same way.

Comment: So I just mention before the inequalities for example for the first term , since $f_n$ is continuous, there is an $\delta > 0 $ such that $|x - y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f_n(x) | < \epsilon/3$. Then in conclusion since $f$ is continuous, $C[a,b]$ is complete?

Comment: For the first and third terms you get no help from continuity, because $f$ and $f_n$ are different functions. You need to use the convergence assumption. Remember that you will get $N$ so that for $n \geq N$ you have an inequality.

Comment: Since the sequence converges uniformly to some $x$  say, there is some $N$ such that $ n \geq N$ implies $|f(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon/3$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Set $n = N +1$ , so $|f(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon/3$ for all x in [a,b].

Comment: You didn't need to introduce the "some $x$"; otherwise you're good.

Comment: @Ian:  Sorry for the necropost. I'm confused: I thought the sequence $\{x^n : x \in [0,1]\}$ , which converges to $0$ for $x \in [0,1) $ and to $1$ when $x=1$ was a counter example, as the sequence of continuous function converges to a discontinuous one. Is this sequence not Cauchy? What am I missing here?

Comment: @MSIS Each sequence of real numbers $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy, but $f_n$ as a sequence in its own right is not Cauchy in the uniform norm. You can see that by taking $m$ way bigger than $n$ and $x=1-1/n$, so $\| f_n - f_m \|$ can't be too much less than $e^{-1}$.