# Can the limit of a sequence of bounded functions be unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis

It is assumed that the sequence of functions converges and that each function is bounded, then can the limiting function be unbounded?

Comment: You should be clear about what "converges" means. I assume you mean "converges point wise".

Comment: You're right,I should've mentioned that. I guess I'm looking for uniform convergence, since the sequence of functions is supposed to be Cauchy wrto the infinite norm.

Comment: The uniform limit of bounded functions is bounded. Just choose $\epsilon =1$ in the definition.

Comment: If the upper bound is unbounded, you have it. Take $f_n(x)=n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if you only have **pointwise** convergence. Take $(f_n)_n$ defined by
$$
f_n(x) = x^2 \mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]}(x), x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

This converges pointwise to the function $f\colon x\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto x^2$, which is not bounded. But each $f_n$ is itself bounded (namely, $\lVert f_n\rVert_\infty = n^2$).

*Following a comment:* however, if it exists, the **uniform** limit (i.e., with regard to the supremum norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$) of a sequence of real-valued bounded functions will be bounded. (Follows e.g. from the fact that the space of bounded-real valued functions is complete for the sup norm, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/168167/75808)); or from a direct proof$^{(\dagger)}$).

---

$(\dagger)$ Taking $\varepsilon = 1$, there exists $N\geq 0$ such that $\lVert f-f_n\rVert_\infty \leq 1$ for all $n\geq N$. In particular, for this specific, fixed $N$, by the triangle inequality
$\lVert f\rVert_\infty \leq \lVert f_N\rVert_\infty+1$.

Comment: You can even make the $f_n$'s continuous if you want, setting $$
f_n(x) = x^2 \mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]}(x) + n^2\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-n,n]}(x), x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: What if I also add the condition that the sequence of functions should be Cauchy with respect to the infinite norm?

Comment: Then you are good: the space of bounded-real valued functions is complete for the sup norm. (see e.g. [these lecture notes](http://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/~fjmliou/Complex/spbounded.pdf) or [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/168167/75808)).

Answer (score 4):

Let $f_n(x)=|x|$ for $|x|\le n$, and let $f(x)=n$ for $|x|\gt n$.

Comment: It is enough to take $f_n(x)=n$ for all $x$.