# Understanding the proof that $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is complete.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, proof-explanation

There is something I don't get from the first anwswer to this question:

[Space of bounded continuous functions is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71121/space-of-bounded-continuous-functions-is-complete?noredirect=1&lq=1)

It's proved for limited functions, but the question is for limited continuous functions, and I can't see where continuity was used in the proof. Can someone explain to me why proving that $B(x)$ is complete imply $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ complete?

Thanks.

Comment: Last sentence in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/92924). The Op already knows that a uniform limit of continuous functions is again continuous. So it boils down to 1. show the space of bounded functions is complete, and 2. note that $C_b$ is a closed subspace of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of the fact that the norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty $ is the norm of the *uniform convergence*. It is known that [if a sequence of continuous functions has a limit in the sense of the uniform convergence, that limit is a continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem).