# Completeness of bounded, convex, continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis

Is the space of bounded, convex, continuous functions with the sup norm complete?

Comment: Surely yes. have you made an attempt? Tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: I am stuck on the convex part. I essentially followed the ideas from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71121/space-of-bounded-continuous-functions-is-complete?rq=1

Comment: Even pointwise limit of convex functions is convex. Apply the definition and take limits on both sides.