# Is the set of bounded functions connected?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

One of my topology homework questions this week says the following:

> Consider the space of bounded functions $B[0, 1]$ on the interval $[0, 1]$
>   with the $d\infty$ metric. 
>   Prove that in the topology induced by the metric $B[0, 1]$ is connected.

I am not sure how to go about proving this, I tried showing that it is path-connected, but since the functions are not necessarily continuous I can't construct a continuous path between them.

The closest answer I've found so far can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71121/space-of-bounded-continuous-functions-is-complete), but I'm not sure how to apply it to my problem, again since the functions I'm dealing with are not continuous.

Comment: You don't need to construct a path of continuous between them. You just need to construct a path of bounded functions between them. My guess is that whatever formula you might wish to use for a continuous path of continuous functions would work perfectly for a continuous path of bounded functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f, g \in B([0,1])$. By definition, there exists $M, M'$ such that for all $x \in [0,1]$, 
$$|f(x)| \leq M \quad \text{and} \quad |g(x)| \leq M'$$

For all $t \in [0,1]$, consider the function $f_t : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f_t : x \mapsto tf(x) + (1-t)g(x)$$

First, $f_t \in B([0,1])$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Indeed it is easy to see that $f_t$ is bounded by $\max(M,M')$.

Moreover, $f_0 = g$ and $f_1 = f$. To see that $t \mapsto f_t$ defines a path between $g$ and $f$, you have to prove that it is continuous. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Define $$\eta = \frac{\varepsilon}{M+M' +1}$$

If $|t'-t| \leq \eta$, then 
$$d_{\infty}(f_t,f_{t'}) = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f_t(x) - f_{t'}(x)| = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} | (t-t')f(x) + (t'-t)g(x)|$$ $$ \leq |t-t'| (M+M') \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{M+M' +1} (M+M') \leq \varepsilon$$

This shows that $t \mapsto f_t$ is continuous, and therefore, $B([0,1])$ is path-connected.