# An equivalent norm of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact topological space and $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space. Let $\mathcal C$ be the space of all continuous functions from $X$ to $E$. Let $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ be the supremum norm on $\mathcal C$. Then $(\mathcal C, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ [is a Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71121/space-of-bounded-continuous-functions-is-complete). We fix a continuous map $g:X \to (0, \infty)$ and define a new norm $[\cdot]$ on $\mathcal C$ by
$$
[f] := \sup_{x\in X} g(x) |f(x)| \quad \forall f \in \mathcal C.
$$

Because $X$ is compact and $g$ continuous, there are $c_1, c_2 >0$ such that $c_1 \le |g(x)| \le c_2$ for all $x \in X$. As such,
$$
c_1 \|\cdot\|_\infty \le [\cdot] \le c_2 \|\cdot\|_\infty.
$$

It follows that $[\cdot]$ is equivalent to $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. Hence  $(\mathcal C, [\cdot])$ is a Banach space.

> Could you confirm if my above understanding is correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Since $g$ must be uniformly continuous we see that there is no problem with continuity of $\sup g(x)$ so your understanding is correct.

Comment: @Piquito: the proof is totally correct as it is. Uniform continuity is off topic here. By the way, $X$ is barely a topological space, so it does not make sense to speak about uniformly continuous functions defined on $X$.